# PHP insert and update in loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I had this php script here, and I want to update the table based on the `$id` and `$name`. Refer to the script, table are successfully update that `id='1' with name='A'` and `id='2' with name='B'`. But name `C,D` doesn't contain an id value yet. Obliviously I need to do insert query. But how to do Insert query in loop based on remaining name that doesn't have an id yet?

And also if size `id > name` I need the remaining `id` that doesn't have `name` to be deleted. Appreciate your help.

```js
<?php
  $id   = "1,2";
  $name = "A,B,C,D";

  $sliptId = explode(",", $id);
  $sliptName = explode(",", $name);

  $sizeOfId = sizeof($sliptId);
  $sizeOfName = sizeof($sliptName );

  if(($sizeOfId < $sizeOfName ) || ($sizeOfId > $sizeOfName)){
    //not even data
    for($x=0; $x< $sizeOfId; $x++ ){
      $sql = "UPDATE tbl
              SET name = '".$sliptName[$x]."' 
              WHERE id = '".$sliptId[$x]."' ";  
      echo $sql;

    }
  }else{
    //even data. Update as normal.
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
  $id   = "1,2";
  $name = "A,B,C,D";

  $sliptId = explode(",", $id);
  $sliptName = explode(",", $name);

  $sizeOfId = sizeof($sliptId);
  $sizeOfName = sizeof($sliptName );

  if($sizeOfId <= $sizeOfName){
    //not even data
    for($x=0; $x< $sizeOfId; $x++ ){
      $sql = "UPDATE tbl
              SET name = '".$sliptName[$x]."' 
              WHERE id = '".$sliptId[$x]."' ";
    }
    for($x=$sizeOfId; $x< $sizeOfName; $x++ ){
      $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl values(null,'".$sliptName[$x]."')";
    }
  }else{
    for($x=0; $x< $sizeOfName; $x++ ){
      $sql = "UPDATE tbl
              SET name = '".$sliptName[$x]."' 
              WHERE id = '".$sliptId[$x]."' ";
    }
  }
```

Comment: One slight issue with this is the duplication of the `UPDATE` statement.  I would also recommend using prepared statements as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could be done:

```
$result = array_map(null, $sliptId, $sliptName);
print_r($result);
// you can see that now you have array of pairs from each `$slipt*` array 
// and where values from first array don't exist - first key is `empty`

foreach ($result as $pair) {
    if (empty($pair[0])) {
        // do Insert
    } else {
        // do Update
    }
}
```